# Airflow: Is airflow initdb command destructive

Tags: airflow

I have a running Airflow server and I am making a config change in `airflow.cfg` which requires to run `airflow initdb` .

Will running `airflow initdb` command for the second time be destructive to existing tables or it will only execute changes according to the new config?

Comment: why not `airflow upgradedb`?
 upgradedb           Upgrade the metadata database to latest version?

Comment: [**@kaxil**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5691525/kaxil) [favours](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f) `upgradedb`

Answer (score 3):

Only destructive command related to airflow database is `airflow resetdb`.

`initdb` and `upgradedb` share the same behavior (except for the first-run).

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run both:

From Airflow source code:

```
def initdb():
    from airflow import models
    from airflow.models import Connection
    upgradedb()
```